# Free Mysql Client tool for running multiple queires and exporting results to single CSV file

Tags: mysql, sql

I am looking for free mysql client which has the ability to run multile sql queries and dump the output to a single csv file.

Example:

```
select department_id, count(1) from employees group by department_id;
select * from departments;
```

The Sql tool should have the options to display the result of both the queries in a single window and also should have feature to export the results to a single csv file.

Answer (score 0):

[MySql-Front](http://www.mysqlfront.de/) imho just fits your needs. Windows-only compatibile, once installed you can go to **SQL EDITOR** tab, write down your queries, look at tabbed results and decide to export them simply right clicking in the result window, click to **export** and choose your desired export format.